# Adding a menu item with jQuery based on inner content of siblings

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I am updating a corporate site for a client, and I am not allowed to edit their html/css/php. When I need to make small changes, like add or remove from the main nav, I have to use a JS override file and jQuery. Like it or not, this is their system.

I am in need of adding a simple item to an unordered list. Targeting the UL is easy, as the nav wrapper has an ID. I don't want to use nth:child since they want this new item between two specific other items, which may change. None of the LI tags have classes or IDs. Inside each LI is a link/anchor. I need to be able to pick the list item based on the text of the inner anchor.

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Something 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Something 2</a></li>
  // Need to insert here, but only because it must go after 
     Something 2, which itself may change positions in the future.
  <li><a href="">Something 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Something 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, how can I most safely do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want..

```
$('#nav li').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() == 'Something 2';
}).after('<li><a href="">Something new</a></li>');
```

---

A more safe way for the comparison would be to trim and convert both string to lowercase.
Additionally you should call your code after the DOMready event

```
$(function(){
    var existingElement = 'Something 2'.toLowerCase();
    $('#nav li').filter(function(){
         var cleanText = $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase();
         return cleanText  == existingElement;
    }).after('<li><a href="">Something new</a></li>');
});
```

Comment: @user1729506, could it be that you are inserting the `Something 2` with javascript/jquery as well ?

Comment: Possibly. Their menu is dynamically generated, but my JS should be executed after everything else has loaded.

Comment: It *should* execute after everything else, but does it ? Is there a live link to the website ?

Comment: I had to double check with them. They made some small change and...boom...now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("ul#nav li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("a").text() == "Something 2";
}).after("<li>your element goes here</li>");​
```

Here's a working fiddle...  http://jsfiddle.net/Sbm7D/

Comment: As with Gaby's, it looks solid. And it works on Fiddle. But it fails when I use it in my override file. Assuming the text I need to find includes something like a copyright symbol or ampersand, how would you target that? & or &amp;? I assumed it looked at it as a literal string, aka &.